# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'in swift 3.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement its required method.

1. **number of rows**
2. **cell for row**

   ```
   extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Allready implemented both method

Comment: extension should be implemented outside the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

UITbleviewDataSource have 2 methos required:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You must implement both

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature for [`numberOfRowsInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview) isn't quite right. You appear to have an extra character there in between `numberOfRows` and `InSection`.

It also looks like you've defined this `extension` inside the class definition. When defining protocol conformance in an `extension`, do this outside of the original `class` definition.